# take a screenshot on ipad using javascript and send it by mail

Tags: javascript, ipad, screenshot

I am making an app with javascript and I need to make a button to make a screenshot of what I have in the screen and send it by mail as an image (it really doesn't matter what kind of image). The app is used in the ipad but I am not sure if it is really important because it is done in html so if there is a way to make a screenshot of what appears within a div will be enough.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible.

Comment: Yeah, I have doubts, too.  What content is in the div?  Are you doing anything with canvas?

Comment: Into the div there are some text, textfields, buttons and some radio selectors. There is no canvas on it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the screenshot?  Confirmation, troubleshooting, etc.?